# How to display Master-Child relation in two separate grids in gridviews

Tags: asp.net

How to display Master-Child relation in two separate grids.
e.g:
Products table: (Master table with productid as primary key)
Productid, ProdDesc

Item table: (Child table with productid as foreign key)
ItemId, ItemDesc, Productid

On selecting a row in Master, all rows related to that productsid should get displayed in the child grid. We need to link the two events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look a the [ASP.NET data tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data), e.g: [Master/Detail Using a Bulleted List of Master Records with a Details DataList](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-bulleted-list-of-master-records-with-a-details-datalist-cs) should give you some hints.